# can I read and write files in tar.gz without decompression?

Tags: python, image, gzip, tar

PROBLEM OUTLINE: can we read and write files in tar.gz without decompression?

I have many `tar.gz` files named like `GF1_PMS1_E72.0_N33.6_20160507_L1A0001568810.tar.gz`
each of the `tar.gz` file contains the files like below:

```
GF1_PMS1_E72.6_N33.6_20160511_L1A0001576267-MSS1.tiff
GF1_PMS1_E72.6_N33.6_20160511_L1A0001576267-MSS1.xml
GF1_PMS1_E72.6_N33.6_20160511_L1A0001576267-MSS1.rpb
GF1_PMS1_E72.6_N33.6_20160511_L1A0001576267-MSS1.jpg
```

I want to read the `tiff`  to numpy array without decompression so I need to get the full path of the `tiff` but I failed by using [tarfile package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html).

below is my codes tried:

```
inpath = 'H:\\alongKKH IMAGES1\\'

def ReadTars(inpath):
    tar_files = os.listdir(inpath)
    for tar in tar_files:
        if tar.split('_')[1] == 'PMS1':
            print tar
            tarname =  tar
            tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(inpath, tar), "r:gz")
            for file_name in tar.getnames():
                if file_name[-4:]=='tiff':
                    print file_name
                    rasterpath = os.path.join(inpath, tarname + '\\' + file_name)
                    array = raster2array(rasterpath)
                    break
        else:
            tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(inpath, tar), "r:gz")
            for file_name in tar.getnames():
                if file_name[-4:]=='tiff':
                    #array = raster2array(os.path.join(inpath, tar, file_name))
                    break
```

`raster2array` is a function to read image to numpy array.

```
def raster2array(rasterfn):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    array = raster.ReadAsArray()
    return array
```

then its throw error below:

```
ERROR 4: `H:\alongKKH IMAGES1\GF1_PMS1_E72.0_N33.6_20160507_L1A0001568810.tar.gz\GF1_PMS1_E72.0_N33.6_20160507_L1A0001568810-MSS1.tiff' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

Who can help me with this I will be gratefull, thank you. I use python for windows.

Comment: Please show the code you tried and also give the traceback of the errors you obtained.

Comment: yeah I add the code and debug information

Comment: @cel did I describe the problem clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tarfile has not read(), zipfile has it,so:

```js
import zipfile
file = zipfile.ZipFile(inpath+'GF1_PMS1_E72.zip', "r")
for name in file.namelist():               
    data = file.read(name)
    print name, len(data), repr(data[:10])
```

If you search and get tarfile's read(), like above.

"rasterfn" is not physical file, then happened error.
GDALOpen, drivers supporting the VSI virtual file API, it is possible to open a file in a .tar/.tar.gz/.tgz archive (see VSIInstallTarFileHandler()):
[VSIInstallTarFileHandler()](https://web.archive.org/web/20180707160913/http://gdal.org:80/cpl__vsi_8h.html#ad6dd983338849e7da4eaa88f6458ab64)

Answer (score 1):

(inpath, tarname + '\' + file_name) -- just a path, don't real file, raster2array support tar? If can't, so "does not exist in the file system".

Comment: I just added the code of `raster2array` in my question, its read GeoTIFF using `gdal` package. I wants to read images without decompression, maybe I am too much fantastic.....